# What am I missing? SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, preg-match, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying to filter out as much as possible to prevent nasty SQL injection, here's my code example, is there anything I'm missing?

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
echo '<div class="col-sm-7">'.$name.'</div>';
```

in my html code ^

```
if( $_POST["name"] ) {
 if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/",$_POST['name'] )) {
     die ("Invalid characters.");
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['name']));
```

so my codes include these above, is there anything I'm missing that could prevent further?

**One more question**

So do I have to filter out my own definition since this data is not come from my form? e.g.

`$currentdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")));`

Comment: Then USE PREPARED STATEMENT with SUBSTITUTION PARAMETERS

Comment: You don't have to filter out any "invalid characters", that does not make any sense. Use escaping (as you already do) or, even better, use "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Comment: And look at the `filter_` set of functions in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

Comment: Yes, have a look at PDO for querying the database. Or even an ORM (propel/doctrine) if you've got many tables and want to be able to manipulate database entites easily in your coce

Comment: is that `pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"` in html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think that you're fine for SQL injection, but I'd take a look at what some of the people are saying in the comments.

On another note, unrelated to SQL injection, you might want to consider using [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on `$name` as well to strip out any unwanted HTML characters.

Comment: You sold me on the *"On another note"* ;-)

Comment: Cheers, I'm adding it into my php now :)